# Syntax for mathematical formula in PL/pgSQL

Tags: postgresql, math, plpgsql, operator-precedence

I have a question in regards to formatting math formulas for PL/pgSQL. I am trying to create a mortgage payment calculator using a given formula. I have been doing lots of searches and cannot figure why my original code doesn't work. I did some searching and found out how the math formula was completed in Python. I inserted the formula and converted it into the right syntax and got the answer I was looking for.

The math formula I'm trying to represent is attached at the bottom.  The math formula from the python tutorial is semantically different so I'm trying to figure out how to fix my formula to make it work given the parameters of the given math formula.

The code I found that worked was:

```
monthly_Payment = P * ((i * ((1+i)^n)) / ((1+i)^n - 1));
```

The code that I made was:

```
monthly_Payment := (P*i) + (i/(1+i)^n - 1);
```

I'm trying to understand how they are different and how I can make my original code work to fit the parameters of my given math formula.

Attached below is the math equation I'm trying to represent.

[image]

Comment: About how to fix your formular: just copy the one you found. About why they are different: I am going to write you an answer below

Answer (score 0):

The expression `(P*i) + (i/(1+i)^n - 1)` is interpreted the following way: (have in mind: brackets before multiplication/division before addition/substraction)

The topmost operator is the `+` in the middle, as you have brackets around both operands.

`(P*i)` is just what it looks like, "`P` times `i`".
Observe, that the `P` has only an effect in this subexpression, while it is multiplied with all the rest in the original formula.

`(i/(1+i)^n - 1)` is viewed as the subtraction of `1` from `i/(1+i)^n` as multiplication/exponentiation happens before subtraction.
But you did not want substraction from the fraction, you wanted subtraction inside of it.

`i/(1+i)^n` is the division of `i` by `(1+i)^n` (as exponentiation is also before multiplication/division).

So this is what happened to you expression. Now I want to shortly explain why the expression you found works. It is not the same representation of the formula you showed, but it will give exactly the same results. Observe, that `i` is the same as `i * ((1+i)^n - 1) / ((1+i)^n - 1)`. This now has the same denominator as the fraction in the picture, thus we can add the enumerators:

```
i * ((1+i)^n - 1) + i
= i * ((1+i)^n - 1) + i * 1
= i * (((1+i)^n - 1) + 1)
= i * ((1+i)^n)
```

The complete fraction is now `i * ((1+i)^n) / ((1+i)^n - 1)`. Now we just need to multiply the `P` to it and we have the same as in the formula you found (up to some unnecessary brackets they added):

```
P * i * ((1+i)^n) / ((1+i)^n - 1)
```

If you want to just write it the way you see it in the picture, do it this way:

```
P * (i + i / ((1+i)^n - 1))
```